# How to properly search for data in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have table in MySQL called movie like this

```
id    movie_name      movie_description
1   the godfather    The_godfather_description
2   the dark Knight  the_dark_knight_description
3   batman begins    batman_begins_description
4   Inception        Inception_description
```

When the query comes I am searching like this for each word in query

```
select movie_name,movie_description from movie where movie_name like(%is%) or movie_description like('%is%')
    select movie_name,movie_description from movie where movie_name like(%god%) or movie_description like('%god%')
   select movie_name,movie_description from movie where movie_name like(%father%) or movie_description like('%father%')
```

Can you tell me proper way to search database so that words like 'is' and 'the' get ignored.  I also want the most relevant articles on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have got you correctly; you are searching for [MySQL full Text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html):

I want to explain you about [Boolean Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html); But I advise you to please go through [Full Text Search using Query Expansion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html) also.

Let's look at the example table:

```
mysql> select * from articles;
+----+-----------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title                 | body                                     |
+----+-----------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PostgreSQL Tutorial   | DBMS stands for DataBase ...             |
|  2 | How To Use MySQL Well | After you went through a ...             |
|  3 | Optimizing MySQL      | In this tutorial we will show ...        |
|  4 | 1001 MySQL Tricks     | 1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ...      |
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL     | In the following database comparison ... |
|  6 | MySQL Security        | When configured properly, MySQL ...      |
+----+-----------------------+------------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('"database comparison"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

+----+-------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title             | body                                     |
+----+-------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL | In the following database comparison ... |
+----+-------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Order matters, when the words are quoted:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('"comparison database"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

When we remove the quotes, it will search for rows, containing words "database" or "comparison":

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('database comparison' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title               | body                                     |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PostgreSQL Tutorial | DBMS stands for DataBase ...             |
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL   | In the following database comparison ... |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Order doesn't matter now:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('comparison database' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title               | body                                     |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PostgreSQL Tutorial | DBMS stands for DataBase ...             |
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL   | In the following database comparison ... |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

If we want to get rows, containing either word "PostgreSQL" or phrase "database comparison", we should use this request:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('PostgreSQL "database comparison"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title               | body                                     |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PostgreSQL Tutorial | DBMS stands for DataBase ...             |
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL   | In the following database comparison ... |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72f54/1)

Make sure, that the words, you are searching for, are not in the [list of stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html), that are ignored.
(and obviously words like 'is','the' are [stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) and those are ignored)

I have explained here only about Boolean Full Text Search; But I advise you to please go through [Full Text Search using Query Expansion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html) also.